# Cant get this hover effect - CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to get the hover effect.  Kindly see the below snippet.

Any help is appreciated

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #1B1B1B;
}

.Nav-Bar ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.Nav-Bar li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Nav-Bar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font: normal 40px "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.Nav-Bar a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffff;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.Nav-Bar:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="Nav-Bar">

  <ul type="none">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>



  </ul>



</div>
```

Comment: you need to target `a::after` on hover

Comment: That is what i have done :/

Comment: Check the below solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select `.Nav-Bar a:hover::after`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #1B1B1B;
}

.Nav-Bar ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.Nav-Bar li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Nav-Bar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font: normal 40px "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.Nav-Bar a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffff;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.Nav-Bar a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="Nav-Bar">
  <ul type="none">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```